# How to fire a function at the same moment of using "new" constructor?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, es6-class

So I have instance of a class and I would like to register all created users.
Ideally would it be to add them to a variable inside of a "User" class or if it's not possible, to global variable "users". I was trying to create self invoking function inside that class, but it didn't work, same with a variable. The goal is to register users, when new user is created by using "new" operator.

**How can I do that ??**

```
    var users;

        class User {
            constructor(email, name) {
                this.email = email;
                this.name = name;  
            }
        }

    var user1 = new User("john@sds.com", "John");
    var user2 = new User("san@wp.com", "San");
```

Comment: Can you not `push` each `new User` to an array and use that as your global.

Comment: You can create a factory that will create your instances of User and systematically add them to your array

Comment: You should show an attempt your tried because then it is possible to tell you why this did not work.

Comment: @t.niese I was basically trying to put self invoking function and add to a global variable, but get errors. Basically i don't know if self invoking functions can be added, cause it was the problem to start with.

Comment: That's what you already wrote in the question? I meant to show some code you have tried and the error message you got. That way you not only get a solution like now, but you will also learn why your attempt did not work and why.

Comment: @IrkenInvader Yes that's the result, but instead of starting with "users.push" I'd like to start with creating new object "var user1= new User.."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on your requisites, you can use weakMaps, and add the new user on each constructor call. This will let you store a weak reference to each new User created, preventing memory leaks, in case any User is deleted.

```
    var users = new WeakMap();

    class User {
        constructor(email, name) {
            this.email = email;
            this.name = name;  
            users.set(this, email)
        }
    }

var user1 = new User("john@sds.com", "John");
var user2 = new User("san@wp.com", "San");
```

If you need to enumerate them , you would need to use an array, but the user should be removed from the array manually , when the user is deleted

```
    var users = [];

    class User {
        constructor(email, name) {
            this.email = email;
            this.name = name;  
            users.push(this)
        }
    }

var user1 = new User("john@sds.com", "John");
var user2 = new User("san@wp.com", "San");
```

Comment: Oh, I didn't know that answer could be that simple. I mean 2nd part was that what I was looking for. Thanks.

Comment: I disagree with adding the newly created instance into something else (An array in this case) inside the constructor. That is too tightly coupled. And is prone to bug, overly complex code or breakage if you forget to create the array. And a `WeakMap` is overkill

Answer (score 1):

No clue if this is close to what you want but give it a try.

```js
var users = [];
var newUser = (function() {
  class User {
    constructor(email, name) {
      this.email = email;
      this.name = name;  
    }
  }

  return function(email, name) {
    var user = new User(email, name);
    users.push(user);
    return user;
  }
 })();
 
 
var user1 = newUser("john@sds.com", "John");
var user2 = newUser("san@wp.com", "San");

console.log(users[0], user1);
console.log(users[1], user2);
```

The IIFE function returns the function that creates the users and places them into the common array. If you want you can place the array into the IIFE function or rearrange things differently.

Answer (score 0):

In this answer given by @colxi, the one issue I see is the User class is tightly coupled to the users array variable. What if in future you need to maintain two or even more separate lists like adminUsers, moderatorUsers.

I would use a function to handle the creation of user and push the user into the users list.

This code is very much similar to what was already suggested but I have implemented [Sepration of Concerns](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns) principle

This way your User class need not worry about the users list or anything else outside of it. We now have a separate function that takes care of updating the users list everytime a new user is created.  And your user class can be moved to a separate js file which can be imported in any other js file that needs to create (any type of ) user.

```
class User {
    constructor(email, name) {
        this.email = email;
        this.name = name;  
    }
}

var users = [];
function createUser(name,email) {
  var user = new User(name,email);
  users.push(user);
  return user;
}

var user1 = createUser("john@sds.com", "John");
var user2 = createUser("san@wp.com", "San");
```